# How do I get perl-support.vim to recognize Perl files?

Tags: perl, vim

I installed *perl-support.vim* into *~/.vim* (unzipped). When I create a new *.pl* file it shows me the default template, which means my installation is successful (I guess). I have already added `filetype plugin on` in *~/.vimrc* & */etc/vimrc*.

How do I enter a `perl-support` command?
[The write up](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/make-vim-as-your-perl-ide-using-perl-supportvim-plugin/) recommends typing <kbd>\isu</kbd> in normal mode for creating a new sub, but the moment I hit <kbd>i</kbd> vim changes into insert mode and nothing intended happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW I hate `perl-support.vim` with a passion. Especially the giant comment blocks and the comments that come after `for`, `while`, `sub` etc blocks. It reminds me too much of Fortran.

Comment: @Sinan -- Hi, Can you suggest anything better ? I have EPIC , want to experiment something new.

Comment: I don't use it myself -- especially since Perl already wants every key that I might be tempted to use as mapleader. But for what else it's worth, it's pretty configurable -- you can change the comment templates, disable hotkeys you don't like, rejigger the menus, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've enabled ftplugins with the `filetype plugin on` command in `.vimrc`, and of course make sure that the file you're editing is recognized as a Perl file (usually, by having a known extension, but you can force the matter by issuing the command `set filetype=perl`. If filetype plugins aren't enabled, or if the filetype isn't recognized, then the rest of perl-support won't get loaded at all.

Comment: Thanks. I have already added "filetype plugin on" in ~/.vimrc & /etc/vimrc , it doesn;t seem to help

Comment: If you're starting work on a new perl file, go ahead and do `vim whatever.pl` instead of waiting until you save to give it a name. Then the filetype will be detected from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

[As recommended by hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571733/how-do-i-get-perl-support-vim-to-recognize-perl-files/1571749#1571749), `set filetype=perl` works.

However, I wanted to do this everytime I open a `.t` test file — which my vim does not recognize as perl files because the interpreter statement is also custom.

I checked out `:help syntax` in vim and saw this:

```
mkdir ~/.vim/ftdetect
cd ~/.vim/ftdetect
vim t.vim
```

which contains

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.t set filetype=perl
```

which means: if the file extension is `.t` then do `set filetype=perl`.

This can be useful for any other custom extension.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to install `Perl::Tags` before most things (esp. `\` commands). Installing `Perl::Tags` made an error message thrown by `filetype plugin on` go away.

```
cpan> install Perl::Tags # make sure you say yes to any offer to install dependancies
```